# Im making an auto updating bash script on android but it doesnt work

Tags: android, bash

```
  Version="1.4"
    Url=wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deadman0/DeadB00st/DeadB00st/UpdateUrl
    if [ $(wget -O linkherestackexchangeletsonly1 | grp -c $Version) -eq 0]; then
    busybox echo "You have the latest update"
    else
    wget $Url -p /sdcard

    busybox sleep 2
    busybox echo "Update Downloaded"
    busybox sleep 2
    busybox echo "--update_package=/emmc
    /DB.zip" > /cache/recovery/command
    busybox sleep 2
    busybox echo "Installing update"
    busybox sleep 1
    busybox echo "3"
    busybox sleep 1
    busybox echo "2"
    busybox sleep 1
    busybox echo "1"
    busybox sleep 1
    busybox echo "Installing..."
    busybox sleep 3
    reboot recovery
    exit
    fi
```

So I tried but I cannot find whats wrong but I'm self taught and I cant do anything else if someone helped me it would be amazing. Its supposed to check for version and if it's not the same download a file which URL takes from a raw GitHub site and then after it has downloaded it flashes it through recovery but I cannot get it to work anyone who can help???

Comment: `url=wget...` then `wget $url`? So you're doing `wget wget -q ...` and wondering why it doesn't work?

Comment: @MarcB i wanted to get a string of what is in the website thats why i used wget wget do you have a suggestion

Comment: yes, read the wget documentation. `wget wget` runs wget, and passes the word `wget` into wget as an argument. it'd be like doing `wget foobar http://`. it's an illegal/unknown argument.